# Trim tabs at the end of a search query

Tags: search

When searching in vim and mostly in netrw I add a tab before hitting enter; muscle memory from other places.

```
/file^I
```

How do I make it so that a tab at the end of a search query is trimmed automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the following mapping to your vimrc:

```
cnoremap <expr> <CR> index(['/', '?'], getcmdtype()) > -1 ? "<C-\>esubstitute(getcmdline(), '\t$', '', '')<CR><CR>" : "<CR>"
```

The basic idea is to remap `<CR>` when you are in the command line mode but only if it was started by a forward or backward search (`/` or `?`).
When `<CR>` is pressed we get the command line content, remove the additional tab at the end and execute the command.

Here is a breakdown for each part of the command:

- `cnoremap`  Only create this mapping in command-line mode [`:h :cnoremap`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Acnoremap)
- `<expr>` Allow use to use an expression in the right hand side of the mapping [`:h :map-<expr>`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Amap-expression)
  Here the expression is

  ```
  index(['/', '?'], getcmdtype()) > -1 ?<C-\>esubstitute(getcmdline(), '\t$', '', '')<CR><CR>" : "<CR>"
  ```
- `<CR>` We are remapping the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

From here the rest of the command is the right hand side of the mapping:

- First we use a ternary expression with the condition

  ```
  index(['/', '?'], getcmdtype()) > -1
  ```

  [`:h getcmdtype()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#getcmdtype%28%29) tells us the current command-line type and we check if it is either `/`, `?` or something else.
- If it is either `/` or `?` then we map `<CR>` to this expression:

  ```
  <C-\>esubstitute(getcmdline(), '\t$', '', '')<CR><CR>
  ```
- If it is another mode we map it to act like a regular `<CR>`

Now the last part about `<C-\>esubstitute(getcmdline(), '\t$', '', '')<CR><CR>`:

- `<C-\>e` ([`:h c_CTRL-\_e`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-%5c_e)) allows to evaluate an expression and use its result to replace what's in the command-line
- So here the epxression is `substitute(getcmdline(), '\t$', '', '')<CR>` which is a simple call to [`:h substitute()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#substitute%28%29) to remove the last tab character. We need the `<CR>` part to validate the replacement as mentionned in the doc.
- The last `<CR>` is used to actually run the newly replaced command.